# Boostrap4: Dashboard with fixed Top-Nav and fixed footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm looking for a Dashboard Layout with bootstrap 4.
Based on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/ the dashboard works already fine.
But combined with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ it seems not to work.
In the end the layout should look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Nav (fixed, sticky)                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|  Sidebar   |               Main (scrollable)                         |
|(scrollable)|                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
|            |                                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       Footer (fixed, sticky)                                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is this possible?
Is there any example how it could work?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mean you want to use [sticky-footer-navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/) on your [Bootstrap dashboard](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard) , Right?

Comment: No, nav-bar on top and a footer for status messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navbar add `navbar-fixed-top` and to footer add:

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px; /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  line-height: 60px; /* Vertically center the text there */
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `Footer` before `</main>` tag.

```
    <footer class="footer" style="text-align: center;">
      <div class="container">
        <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </main>
```